# Getting "Class loaders have different class objects" error when trying to use custom kotlin spigot library

Tags: kotlin, gradle, minecraft, spigot

I have two separate kotlin projects that communicate with each other, one being a library and one being a project using said library. In the library I have the following data class:

```kotlin
data class MelodiaGUIItem(..., val clickFunc: (InventoryClickEvent) -> Unit)
```

and in the implementation I use it as such:

```kotlin
MelodiaGUIItem(...) { e: InventoryClickEvent -> e.whoClicked.sendMessage("Greenhouse") }
```

However, when used like this, I get the following error:

`[T]he class loader 'ScovillePlugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar' @253c7e22 of the current class, dev/meluhdy/scovilleplugin/gui/pk/PkGUI, and the class loader 'Melodia-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar' @119fc272 for the method's defining class, dev/meluhdy/melodia/gui/MelodiaGUIItem, have different Class objects for the type kotlin/jvm/functions/Function1 used in the signature`

I've made sure the kotlin and gradle version for both projects are the same, so I'm genuinely confused how there's a conflict with `kotlin/jvm/functions/Function1`, a kotlin built-in type.
I've also attempted looking up the error but a lot of the results are for conflicting definitions for custom functions, not built-in ones like this.

I'm not entirely sure where to even start with this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you linking the two projects together so that you end up with different class loaders for each one?

Comment: They're both plugins being loaded by paperspigot. One is a library, and the other is dependent on that library.